# I need to "textJoin" multiple lookups in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I hope you can help me! I work for a company that books Food Trucks for Apartment buildings and each month we send out a form to get which dates and buildings each truck wants to do. What I am looking to do is take One date for one building and show all the trucks that responded in one cell.

I've been lost all day researching a solution for this but I have tried an Index/Match Combo and couldn't get it to work at all. My issue is that we do this every month and I would not like to hard code the formula into it because I just redid the whole spreadsheet to make it more dynamic. This is the last part that I have not been able to figure out.

In the previous version, I used a simple `textjoin` formula to bring all the trucks into the one cell and had columns that the trucks were hard-coded into. `=TEXTJOIN(", ",True,'Named Ranges'!$F$3:$F$63)` was the formula I used and each day and building had its own column where the data would go. However, the new version of the data is dynamic and the `textjoin` formula needs to look for the column with the specific date and building.

Here is the link to the spreadsheet any help you could provide would be awesome!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RJeTMI1EI8iXr2MV2MmRUU1DZN1irfVgxMU8jlHHKaI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you provide an example of the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

paste in B11 and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(
 INDIRECT("Responses!"&ADDRESS(4, MATCH(B8, Responses!$3:$3, 0), 4)&":"&
            SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(4, MATCH(B8, Responses!$3:$3, 0), 4), 4, ))<>"",
 Responses!$B$4:$B, )), "no cars"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to get the name of the trucks in there not the "Yes"